# Rescalling image that isn't called specifically as an image in HTML

Tags: html, django, image

This is going to be a very novice question. I am working with a Django application and for the first time I am having to edit the HTML, something I haven't worked on in years and even when I did I was not a high level.

The current code has something like the following written:

```
<div class="x">
    %(image)s
</div>
```

I have never seen this '%(image)s' syntax before and anything I google appears to refer to string substitution and things like this. The class also has a max width of 16.6667% but the image does not rescale to this width. I have tried to add in widths to the div but with no luck and I believe it may be due to the way the image is being fed through to the html.

Any insight on what an earth is happening here so I can find where the image is defined and potentially generate a smaller one at that stage would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out it was a string substitution being fed by a python file in another app. If you are having this issue I suggest going through all the modules in your Django app and searching the files for the image name and you should find some python file defining some html code somewhere.